# How to back up KeePass 2.46 installed on Windows 10 to a USB stick?

Tags: keepass

I have spent several hours to no avail trying to figure out / find out by reading how to back up the free KeePass 2.46 that I had installed on Windows 10. I found [instructions](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/wiki/Backup/), but I do not understand terms like "*plug-in*", "*trigger*", or "*temporary location on your hard disk*".

Answer (score 1):

I have KeePass here.

You would back up the Database (not the app - it can be reinstalled).

The default name of the database is Password Database.kdbx

The location is where you put it. Look also in Windows 10 Documents as it may have gone there.

Open Windows File Explorer and look in the locations above to find your database. Once found, you can copy it to any place you wish.

You can save the newest copy of the database using File, Save / Save as. You can save to a USB key at this point as well. That works very well. You can also Exit Keepass and that will require saving if you changed passwords.  These are very close in operation. Copying as I do it does not require Keepass to be open. Almost just personal preference.

Be sure to save before copying the database elsewhere (different computers).

Here is a pictures of what you are looking for in KeePass . You can backup and / or copy the file to any other computer or location. I keep KeePass on three computers.

Have a main KeePass computer and then after you make password changes, re-copy the database to where you keep copies and replace the other location with the newer database.

You would need the mobile app if you wish to put KeePass on phone. I have not done that yet (not yet a need).

Here is a picture of the Save method.

[image]

Here is a picture of the Database Name and where it is located

[image]

Comment: "Open Windows Explorer and look in the locations above to find your database. Once found, you can copy it to any place you wish." Did you mean "Open Windows File Explorer"?

Comment: If Keepass is not running (I do not always have it running) then the database can be located with Windows File explorer and found / copied. I did clarify this.. Thanks.